# Android : getting file path like (downloads/my_downloads/286) this using open with option using chrome document viewer

Tags: java, android, download, filepath

I am downloading a sample document pdf ,doc,docx etc.file using chrome browser and the downloaded document gets opened automatically by default chrome drive viewer and then i will use open with option and select my own app to read the document but app gets crashed , am getting the selected file path (downloads/my_downloads/286) like this only in marshmallow ,is there any solution to get absolute filename and file path. This is not occurring in lollipop and lower versions ,need solution to get absolute file path..

Answer (score 0):

> is there any solution to get absolute filename and file path

No, because there is no requirement for there to be a file, let alone one that you can access via the filesystem.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri` that you are given. That will work for `Uri` values with `file`, `content`, and `android.resource` schemes.

Comment: Thanks for your response , I have downloaded the pdf file using content resolver ,but i can't able retrieve the file name of the selected file is there any way to get file name of the downloaded file using content resolver?

Comment: if i get the cursor count it returns 0 ,is there any solution to get the name of the downloaded  file...

Comment: @Praveen: There is no requirement that there *be* a name. You are welcome to use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` and `getName()` to get a display name, but it may not represent a filename.